# autocomplete suggestion list wrong z-index, how can i change?

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, z-index

seems that my autocomplete list its < z-index than some elements of my site so its under exposed, what class shall i edit?

with editCSS i sow those class, and add (z-index of my site but few tings doesn't affect is 1)

```
.ui-corner-all, .ui-menu-item, #ingredientes_s.ui-autocomplete-input{z-index: 20;}
```

but stills same problem..

Comment: Try using firebug/IE developer tools to target the elements that are not showing properly. Then you can determine which css class you need to redefine.

Comment: thanks! tried, but seems to be bore class on table..

Comment: I had this problem as well.
The answer is here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6762760/211362

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI Autocomplete options list calculates its z-index value by taking the z-index of the text input it's being attached to and adds 1 to that value.

So you can give a z-index of 999 to the text input the autocomplete will have a z-index value of 1000

Taken from http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5489

```
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" style="z-index:999;" name="foo">
```